# Reference a eclipse plugin from a regular project

Tags: maven, eclipse-plugin, tycho

this is a more conceptual question:

I want to create an application which uses the WALA framework, which itself is packaged as a eclipse plugin, built with maven-tycho. When I try to add this as an dependency no transitive dependency gets resolved, because they are covered by the tycho build.

This is the pom of the WALA project I need at least https://github.com/wala/WALA/blob/master/com.ibm.wala.core/pom.xml

Should my application be a OSGI Bundle itself or can I create a regular jar with it without having much trouble? Which approach is more practical?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have seen it correctly, `wala.core` has only two dependencies `wala.util` and `wala.shrike` (util has none, shrike depends on util). So you might as well simply include all three dependencies in your project.

On the long haul, however, you might should indeed consider creating an osgi application instead.

Comment: Is there no common pattern how to use osgi bundles in "normal" Java?

Comment: OSGI Bundles are basically jar files. They could be used as normal dependencies, but you would need to handle the dependencies yourself.

Comment: No chance that tycho might have a feature to resolve transitive dependencies?

Comment: Yes, if you use tycho, transitive dependencies will be resolved. But the decision whether to create an OSGI or a regular application depends on what you want to create. If you can run your application in an osgi container, this would be a viable solution.